# Create zip file from byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, zip, .net-4.5

I am trying to create a Zip file in .NET 4.5 (System.IO.Compression) from a series of byte arrays.  As an example, from an API I am using I end up with a `List<Attachment>` and each `Attachment` has a property called `Body` which is a `byte[]`.  How can I iterate over that list and create a zip file that contains each attachment?

Right now I am under the impression that I would have to write each attachment to disk and create the zip file from that.

```
//This is great if I had the files on disk
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
//How can I create it from a series of byte arrays?
```

Comment: Have you looked at the rest of the classes in [System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Compression.aspx), particularly those that have _Stream_ in their name?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/gzipstream
http://softdeveloping.blogspot.in/2012/01/example-of-compressing-and.html

Comment: @AustinSalonen - I may be missing something, but, I don't think I can have a GZipStream with multiple files as the output.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

After a little more playing around and reading I was able to figure this out.  Here is how you can create a zip file (archive) with multiple files without writing any temporary data to disk:

```
using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Create an archive and store the stream in memory.
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false)) {
        foreach (var caseAttachmentModel in caseAttachmentModels) {
            //Create a zip entry for each attachment
            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(caseAttachmentModel.Name);

            //Get the stream of the attachment
            using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(caseAttachmentModel.Body))
            using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open()) {
                //Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
                originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
            }
        }
    }

    return new FileContentResult(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "Filename.zip" };
}
```

Comment: is it cleaner if one uses `Close()` instead of nested `using`s?

Comment: @sports - What are you calling `Close()` on?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson Cannot access closed stream? Remove the outer using :-)

Comment: Friendly tip - If the ZipArchive class is unavailable, add a reference to the assembly: Right-Click `References` -> `Add Reference`. Under `Assemblies`, search for `System.IO` and check off `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` and `System.IO.Compression`.

Comment: What is caseAttachmentModels? Also where is the byte[]?

Comment: @sports I reformatted the code to use better layout of `using` statements. If you have multiple `using`s in a row without code in between, you do not have to nest them.

Comment: what is populating compressedFileStream?

Comment: @doganak The `compressedFileStream` is passed into the constructor of the `ZipArchive` object and used internally.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I was wondering if there's actually compression happening here? Since this script only copies streams, I can't see if the resulting archive actually is compressed or not. Any idea?

Comment: @Glubus It looks like there are 3 options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.compressionlevel(v=vs.110).aspx.  I believe the default is optimal.

Comment: I used this but the "compressedFileStream" is always at 0 length... any ideas?

Comment: @Demodave `caseAttachmentModels` are list of Attachments. `caseAttachmentModel.Body` is the byte[]. Read the question ;)

Comment: @ZakariaSahmane if the "compressedFileStream" is 0 length, you need to put 
 curly brackets after the first "using": 
using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream()) {
using () {} ... compressedFileStream.ToArray() ...
}

Comment: compressedFileStream is always 0 bytes .please help me .

Comment: @SayedAzharuddin I just edited the answer. `ZipArchiveMode.Update` should be `ZipArchiveMode.Create` or it won't work. I had the same issue as you.

Comment: I used this instead, which is a bit simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927574/create-zip-file-in-memory-from-bytes-text-with-arbitrary-encoding

Comment: @krillgar your edit introduced a bug. The original has the return statement after the `zipArchive` is closed. By removing the nesting, you also now have the return statement inside the `zipArchive` `using` statement. By not disposing, the archives are not valid.

Comment: @Zeph is correct. I had to add the braces around the original using statement and move the return statement one level out to make my zipArchive valid.

Answer (score 8):

This is a variation of the great accepted answer posted by the OP. However, this is for WebForms instead of MVC.  I'm working with the assumption that caseAttachmentModel.Body is a byte[]

Essentially everything is the same except with an additional method that sends the zip out as a Response.

```
using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    //Create an archive and store the stream in memory.
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false))         {
     foreach (var caseAttachmentModel in caseAttachmentModels) {
        //Create a zip entry for each attachment
        var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(caseAttachmentModel.Name);

        //Get the stream of the attachment
        using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(caseAttachmentModel.Body)) {
                using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open()) {
                    //Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
                    originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sendOutZIP(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "FileName.zip");
}

private void sendOutZIP(byte[] zippedFiles, string filename)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "application/x-compressed";
    Response.Charset = string.Empty;
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Public);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    Response.BinaryWrite(zippedFiles);
    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
    Response.OutputStream.Close();
    Response.End();
}
```

I would also like to point out that advice given by @Levi Fuller on references in the accepted answer is spot on!

Comment: Can we set password to zip file?

Comment: The documentation of the System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't show any options to password a zip file. According to this (oldish) thread (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c2303b11-cf85-41ea-b1a2-caf8b4042bda/systemiocompression-and-passwords?forum=netfxbcl) there is no password functionality in the .NET stuff and it suggests finding a third party library.

Answer (score 2):

GZipStream and DeflateStream seem like they would let you use steams/byte arrays to solve your problem, but maybe not with a compression file format usable by most users. (ie, your file would have a .gz extension) If this file is only used internally, that might be okay.

I don't know how you might make a ZIP using Microsoft's libraries, but I remember this library supporting the sort of things you might find useful:
http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/

It's licensed under LGPL.

Comment: I need the end result to be multiple files which I don't believe GZipStream supports.

Comment: OK, then try SevenZipSharp. It's built around the 7-zip library, but that can compress to a .zip file as well. There may also be similar libraries on Codeplex.