# Asp.net Multiple files download

Tags: asp.net

Im trying to search and download the files uploaded to the database,I can able to retrieve the files from the database.
Downloading single file works but cant download multiple files at a time,I have read about downloading as a zip file,Can anyone help??????

```
     using (sampledbase dbcontext = new sampledbase ())
       {

           ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
           long id = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["id"]);
           System.Nullable<long> fileid = id;
           var query = dbcontext.searchfile(ref fileid );

          foreach (var i in query)
           {
               byte[] binarydata = i.Data.ToArray();
               Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename =\"{0}\"", i.Name));
               Response.BinaryWrite(binarydata);
               Response.ContentType = i.ContentType;
               Response.End();
           }
       }
```

Comment: why you can't add the files into the Zip file and download the Zip file instead of multiple files ?

Comment: how to zip all the files from the database???

Comment: my approach would be creating hidden links or forms tag and send request using them to the required files and downloading them one after another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using ZipFile so you are in the right direction. In order to zip your files, you can save your files in a directory and zip the directory using this code :

```
string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
```

In your case, look at the data type returned by dbcontext.searchfile() and save the content to a directory using something like StreamWriter. Looking at your code, the type seems to be a byte[], you can see this link to learn how to save the bytes in a file : [Write bytes to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397235/write-bytes-to-file)

Another solution is to zip directly the bytes[] : [Create zip file from byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217077/create-zip-file-from-byte)