# create zip from byte[] and return to browser

Tags: c#, stream, zip, compression

I want to create a zip-file and return it to the browser so that it downloads the zip to the downloads-folder.

```
              var images = imageRepository.GetAll(allCountryId);

        using (FileStream f2 = new FileStream("SudaAmerica", FileMode.Create))
        using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(f2, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
        {
            foreach (var image in images)
            { 
                gz.Write(image.ImageData, 0, image.ImageData.Length);
            }
            return base.File(gz, "application/zip", "SudaAmerica");
        }
```

i have tried the above but then i get an error saying the stream is disposed.

Is this possible or should i use another library then gzipstream?

Comment: Copy the gz stream into a memory stream and don't close it.  The File handler will do that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is exactly what it says: you are handing it something based on `gz`, but `gz` gets disposed the moment you leave the `using`.

One option would be to wait until *outside* the `using` block, then tell it to use the *filename* of the thing you just wrote (`"SudaAmerica"`). However, IMO you shouldn't actually be writing a file here *at all*. If you use a `MemoryStream` instead, you can use `.ToArray()` to get a `byte[]` of the contents, which you can use in the `File` method. This requires no IO access, which is a win in about 20 different ways. Well, maybe 3 ways. But...

```
var images = imageRepository.GetAll(allCountryId);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, false))
    {
        foreach (var image in images)
        { 
            gz.Write(image.ImageData, 0, image.ImageData.Length);
        }
    }
    return base.File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", "SudaAmerica");
}
```

Note that a gzip stream is *not* the same as a `.zip` archive, so I very much doubt this will have the result you want. Zip archive creation is available elsewhere in the .NET framework, but it is *not* via `GZipStream`.

You probably want [`ZipArchive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! ZipArchive worked perfectly :) I used the example from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217077/create-zip-file-from-byte

Comment: @DanielGustafsson no problem! thanks for being receptive to the hint - sometimes people react badly if you point out this type of thing

Comment: @DanielGustafsson note: if `image.ImageData` is a `byte[]`, the *innermost* `MemoryStream` in that linked example is redundant - you can use a `Write` very similar to your `gz.Write(...)`, but `zipEntryStream.Write(...)`.