# C# and EmguCV: ZIP image from memory

Tags: c#, windows, zip, emgucv

I want to add a set of images to a ZIP file in C#. I use EmguCV to save the images. Currently I save the image locally first and then add to ZIP as follows.

***Is there anyway to add the images to ZIP file directly on the fly without saving locally?***

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I could not locate a clear answer for days.

```
using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(this.path, FileMode.Create))
{
  using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < clouds.Count; i++)
    {
      string imageCname = kinectId + "_" + dateTimes[i] + ".jpg";
      imageCt = imageCs[i];
      imageCt.Save("imageCt.jpg");
      zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(@"imageCt.jpg", imageCname);
      Console.WriteLine("Flushing rgb " + i + " of " + clouds.Count);
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

As suggested by #CarbineCoder I edited the code as follows. It saves a file. But cannot open as an image. I guess, it just save only the Byte steam. What else may I do to save it as a jpeg image.

```
string imageCname = kinectId + "_" + dateTimes[i] + ".jpg";
imageCt = imageCs[i];
ZipArchiveEntry zipEntryC = zipArchive.CreateEntry(imageCname);

using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(imageCt.Bytes))
{
  using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntryC.Open())
  {
    originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try these solutions - to use zipArchive.CreateEntry() - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232414/creating-a-zip-archive-in-memory-using-system-io-compression http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217077/create-zip-file-from-byte

Comment: @CarbineCoder, I edited the code as you suggested. It saves a file. But cannot open as an image. What may I doing wrong? I guess, I should specify the image format somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the code you changed?

use zipArchive.CreateEntry() solutiuon specified in-

[Create zip file from byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217077/create-zip-file-from-byte)

[Creating a ZIP Archive in Memory Using System.IO.Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232414/creating-a-zip-archive-in-memory-using-system-io-compression)

Yes you might need to specify the extension of the file like  `zipArchive.CreateEntry("FileName.jpg")`. This might solve your problem

Comment: Yes, I created the ZipArchive with the filename. Sorry that I did not include it in the updated code. Now corrected the mistake.

Comment: whats the problem now

Comment: With the help of yours, finally it works. Thank you. I will post the corrected code for anyone looking for similar solution as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the issue with the CarbineCoder suggestion. Posted below is the working code.

```
string imageCname = kinectId + "_" + dateTimes[i] + ".jpg";
imageCt = imageCs[i];

ZipArchiveEntry zipEntryC = zipArchive.CreateEntry(imageCname);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntryC.Open())
  {
    System.Drawing.Image userImage = imageCt.ToBitmap();
    userImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
  }
}
Console.WriteLine("Flushing rgb " + i + " of " + clouds.Count);
```