# how to convert byte array to zip archive in c#?

Tags: php-ziparchive

I have a byte array of ziparchive in database. when i retrieve the data from database and try  to convert back to Ziparchive it throws an error. Is there any way to convert to zipArchive from the byte array?

Comment: Did my Answer work @Eraiarasu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17220824/1201725) I think it is possible to convert your stream byte array to zip archive:

```
using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    //Create an archive and store the stream in memory.
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false)) {
        foreach (var caseAttachmentModel in caseAttachmentModels) {
            //Create a zip entry for each attachment
            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(caseAttachmentModel.Name);

            //Get the stream of the attachment
            using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(caseAttachmentModel.Body)) {
                using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open()) {
                    //Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
                    originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return new FileContentResult(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "Filename.zip" };
}
```

Here, with the line `new FileContentResult(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "Filename.zip" };`, if you already converted into zip file then you can convert your stream byte array into zip archive like this:

```
new FileContentResult(your_stream_byte_array, "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "Filename.zip" };
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already created the zipfile and stream byte array stored in database. Now i want convert that byte array to ZipArchive

Comment: So I guess last step is to use your stream byte array and create your zip archive like this: `new FileContentResult(your_stream_byte_array, "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "Filename.zip" };` here,